# Filter dictionary of tuples with duplicated first element of the values based on some condition

Tags: python

Sample input data in which Value1 is duplicated across several keys

```
{'Key1': ('Value1', '28.302', '30', '131', '10', '321'), 
 'Key2': ('Value2', '42.373', '44', '98', '1252', '1413'), 
 'Key3': ('Value1', '34.048', '4', '375', '22', '1275'), 
 'Key4': ('Value3', '47.561', '82', '159', '901', '1146'), 
 'Key5': ('Value1', '35.821', '214', '279', '82', '282')}
```

Desired results in which key1 and key3 have been filtered out because the second element of Value1 is the highest in Key5.

```
{'Key2': ('Value2', '42.373', '44', '98', '1252', '1413'), 
 'Key4': ('Value3', '47.561', '82', '159', '901', '1146'), 
 'Key5': ('Value1', '35.821', '214', '279', '82', '282')}
```

My attempts thus far have failed and they are probably useless to post them here!

Comment: Can You fully describe the filter rule?

Comment: Failed attempts are not useless to post; one could be just a hair away from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably want to do this in a multi-step process.

```
import itertools

d = {'Key1': ('Value1', '28.302', '30', '131', '10', '321'), 'Key2': ('Value2', '42.373', '44', '98', '1252', '1413'), 'Key3': ('Value1', '34.048', '4', '375', '22', '1275'), 'Key4': ('Value3', '47.561', '82', '159', '901', '1146'), 'Key5': ('Value1', '35.821', '214', '279', '82', '282')}

filtered = dict(
    max(group, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    for _, group in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(d.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1]),
        key=lambda tup: tup[1][0]                 
    )
)
# {'Key5': ('Value1', '35.821', '214', '279', '82', '282'), 
#  'Key2': ('Value2', '42.373', '44', '98', '1252', '1413'), 
#  'Key4': ('Value3', '47.561', '82', '159', '901', '1146')}
```

The process is:

1. use `sorted()` to rearrange `d.items()` so that all identical [first element of tuple] are next to each other (otherwise `groupby()` won't work)
2. use `itertools.groupby()` to collect all items with the same first element of that tuple.
3. use `max()` to take the max of each group
4. convert the list of `(key, value)` tuples back into a dict

You can insert another `sorted()` between steps 3 and 4 if you want the keys inserted in a specific order - but it's a dict, so order ought not matter.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use a pandas data frame approach

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Key1': ('Value1', '28.302', '30', '131', '10', '321'),
     'Key2': ('Value2', '42.373', '44', '98', '1252', '1413'),
     'Key3': ('Value1', '34.048', '4', '375', '22', '1275'),
     'Key4': ('Value3', '47.561', '82', '159', '901', '1146'),
     'Key5': ('Value1', '35.821', '214', '279', '82', '282')}

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()
data.rename(columns={"index": "Key", 0: "Value"}, inplace=True)
data = data.set_index(["Key", "Value"], drop=True).sort_index(ascending=True)
```

At this point you have turned your dict into a multiindex dataframe:

```
                  1    2    3     4     5
Key  Value                               
Key1 Value1  28.302   30  131    10   321
Key2 Value2  42.373   44   98  1252  1413
Key3 Value1  34.048    4  375    22  1275
Key4 Value3  47.561   82  159   901  1146
Key5 Value1  35.821  214  279    82   282
```

This allows you do to all kind of operations. Finding you wanted rows would be like:

```
max_rows = list()
sort_column = 1
for key_name, df in data.groupby("Value"):
    max_row = df.sort_values(sort_column, ascending=False).head(1)
    max_rows.append(max_row)
result = pd.concat(max_rows).sort_index()
print(result)
```

This gives you a Dataframe which looks like this:

```
                  1    2    3     4     5
Key  Value                               
Key2 Value2  42.373   44   98  1252  1413
Key4 Value3  47.561   82  159   901  1146
Key5 Value1  35.821  214  279    82   282
```

I you need a dict with the tuples back you can do:

```
result2 = dict()
for index, row in result.iterrows():
    result2[index[0]] = tuple([index[1]] + row.values.tolist())
```

giving the desired result:

```
 {'Key2': ('Value2', '42.373', '44', '98', '1252', '1413'), 
  'Key4': ('Value3', '47.561', '82', '159', '901', '1146'), 
  'Key5': ('Value1', '35.821', '214', '279', '82', '282')}
```

Most likely the solution by Green Cloak Guy is faster, but having turned dicts into dataframes (multiindex) it is probably easier to manipulate your data

Answer (score 1):

- First get all dictionary keys as value not reference by using copy method(when dictionary change **all_keys** not will not be affected)
- Declare **current_key** to access current key
- First loop to access all keys
- Every time return the new length of keys
- Second loop to check if current key equal another key
- If condition return true remove this key from dictionary and leave iterator
- Every time end second loop increment current key by one

**Edit**

In the second loop we don't need dict keys every time we can get it once in first loop

**Edit 2**

When remove key from dict we shouldn't increment current key because the next one will be current so i add flag to control it.

```js
my_dic = {'Key1': ('Value1', '28.302', '30', '131', '10', '321'),
            'Key2': ('Value2', '42.373', '44', '98', '1252', '1413'),
            'Key3': ('Value1', '34.048', '4', '375', '22', '1275'),
            'Key4': ('Value3', '47.561', '82', '159', '901', '1146'),
            'Key5': ('Value1', '35.821', '214', '279', '82', '282')}
# all keys
all_keys = my_dic.copy().keys()
# cuurent key
current_key = 0

for key in all_keys:
    # get new number of keys
    number_of_keys = len(my_dic)
    # new dictionaty keys
    dict_keys = list(my_dic.keys())
    # flag
    flag = True
    for index in range(current_key+1, number_of_keys):

        # if condation return true remove this key
        # from dictionary and leave second loop
        if(my_dic[key][0] == my_dic[dict_keys[index]][0]):
            my_dic.pop(key)
            flag = False
            break
    # when flag return true this mean we should jump to next kay
    # if not we should still becasue next element will be the current
    if flag:
        current_key += 1
```

you can build function to use this code any time

```js
# filterDictionary
def filterDictionary(user_dict):
    """
        this function return new dictionary after filter it
        params:
            - user_dict: the user dictionary to fitler it
    """
    # get copy from dictionary To not be affected by any change
    user_dict = user_dict.copy()

    # all keys
    all_keys = user_dict.copy().keys()
    
    # cuurent key
    current_key = 0

    for key in all_keys:
        # get new number of keys
        number_of_keys = len(user_dict)

        # new dictionaty keys
        dict_keys = list(user_dict.keys())

        # flag
        flag = True

        for index in range(current_key+1, number_of_keys):
            # if condation return true remove this key
            # from dictionary and leave second loop
            if(user_dict[key][0] == user_dict[dict_keys[index]][0]):
                user_dict.pop(key)
                flag = False
                break
        # when flag return true this mean we should jump to next kay
        # if not we should still becasue next element will be the current
        if flag:
            current_key += 1
        
    
    return user_dict

my_dic = {'Key1': ('Value2', '28.302', '30', '131', '10', '321'),
            'Key2': ('Value2', '42.373', '44', '98', '1252', '1413'),
            'Key3': ('Value3', '34.048', '4', '375', '22', '1275'),
            'Key4': ('Value2', '47.561', '82', '159', '901', '1146'),
            'Key5': ('Value1', '35.821', '214', '279', '82', '282')}

print(filterDictionary(my_dic))
```